# How do I correctly set up a Unity animation to move?

Tags: unity, animation

I downloaded a custom .fbx model from the asset store, imported it to my project and placed it in my scene. I then created an animator controller and added it to the object.

To get the animations (that came with the model) into the animator tab, I dragged them onto the model in the hierarchy. I then set the one animation to default and pressed play, but in the game window, the model didn't move.

What might be going on?

The only time it did something was when I set it to "play from start" but that made it go through all the animations.

I'm quite new to Unity 4. If you need any extra information, please ask.

Comment: once you create an animator you should drag animations in the animator view to create states and transitions between them.  
[this](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth/player-animator-controller) lesson in the project stealth tutorial will explain you things